# Proper ActiveRecord modeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 different Models

`Bid` `Order` `Printer`

```
class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :printer
end
```

I would like to be able to view all of a printers orders they have bidded on, but with my current structure I cannot do it.  it would be something like `@printer.bids.orders`

How can accomplish this?  Would I have to change Order to have `belongs_to Printer`, or `has_many: bids through orders`?  Something along those lines?

Comment: in rails guides look for has_many through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to declare printer like this:

```
class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
  has_many :orders, through: :bids
end
```

This should work